# Logstash local configuration

Tags: spring-boot, logstash

Im trying to configure local logstash config with spring boot in yml format.
Here it is:

```
appenders:
  logstash:
    enabled: true
    input-type: tcp
    destination: 127.0.0.1:4560
```

and after running app I catch in console:

```
WARN in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[logstash] - Log destination 127.0.0.1:5010: connection failed. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I checked all listeners and the port is not in use. I seems to be easy to fix but I dk how.

Comment: to be sure: is Logstash running and can you ping it from the host where your spring boot app is running?

Comment: If it is the case and it is still giving you the same result, if your host is dualstacked try either setting the host on logstash to 0.0.0.0 to make it listen on IPv4.
If you want to use IPv6 try using [::1]:4560

Comment: Thanks, but it seems I missed running elk container locally.